# find or locate commands in linux do not return an existing file

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a script file on my file system (on my UBUNTU 16.04 system) 
`/etc/spark2/conf/spark-env.sh`

Using find command or locate (event after update db) does not seem to list this file.
I can't figure out why.

`sudo find / -name  spark-env.sh`

It does find other versions of this file but not the one I am after
I would like to know why

I tried on an Ubuntu 14 system install and I have the same problem

Comment: It would be really helpful if you add which distro you are on, and the exact command output for both `locate` and `find`

Comment: Are there any links in the path? By default `find` does not follow follow symbolic links.

Comment: @mtak Ubuntu 16. Sorry

Comment: @AFH not that I know of

Comment: If you enter `ls -ld /etc /etc/spark2 /etc/spark2/conf` then you will confirm one way or the other: do not add a trailing `/` to any of the paths.

Comment: @MehdiLAMRANI, Which Ubuntu 16? 16.04 or 16.10?

Comment: Ubuntu  16.04 __